# JavaFX Notification with ControlsFX

Tags: notifications, tableview, javafx-8, controlsfx

I am doing Stocks market app, I need to display Order status changes to user. I came across ControlsFX Notification. From doc example, it looks like we can only specify simple text for it's content.

```
Notifications.create()
             .title("Title")
             .text("Hello Notification")
             .darkStyle()
             .show();
```

Is there a way to specify content Node, eg: TableView? As I would like to group a bunch of messages together, present in TableView / ListView, then show in single notification.

If not achievable with ControlsFX, any other recommendation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `Node` to display unsing [`graphic`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/Notifications.html#graphic-javafx.scene.Node-).

```
Notifications.create()
        .darkStyle()
        .title("Title")
        .graphic(new Rectangle(600, 400, Color.RED)) // sets node to display
        .hideAfter(Duration.seconds(10))
        .show();
```

Comment: I tried using .graphic(tableview). I am developing on Mac Book, the notification appears corrupted with graphic, showing many notifications appear overlapping each other, whereas it works OK with only text. Any idea why? I will find a way to upload screenshots here.

Comment: I describe the Notification appears as corrupted issue here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559932/controlsfx-notification-graphic-corrupted . Any idea?

Comment: My problem is fixed, I answered my own question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559932/controlsfx-notification-graphic-corrupted . Thanks!