# ControlsFX Notification Graphic corrupted

Tags: notifications, tableview, javafx-8, controlsfx

I am using ControlsFX Notification to display a group of messages. Text is not perfect way for me, so I present data in TableView.

```
 import org.controlsfx.control.Notifications;
 ......


 TableView<NotificationModel> notificationTable = new TableView();

 ......

 Notifications notification = Notifications.create()
            .title("Transaction Notifications")
            .text(null)
            .graphic(notificationTable)
            .position(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT)
            .hideAfter(Duration.minutes(1));

 notification.show();
```

In normal case, notification looks like this:

[image: Notification - OK]

But notification appears corrupted most of the time, as below. It seems showing > 1 Notification, overlaying on each other.

[image: Notification - corrupted]

I tested ControlsFX sample jar file, choosing "Graphic Options: Total-replacement graphics". It shows same corrupted behaviour.

[image: Notification - Corrupted]

It looks like a bug from ControlsFX, when showing non-text notification with graphics. Anyone facing similar issue? I am developing on macOS Sierra 10.12.2, ControlsFX 8.40.12.

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem fixed by wrapping TableView in AnchorPane, then set as graphic of Notifications.

```
  AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane(notificationTable);

  Notifications notification = Notifications.create()
          .title("Transaction Notifications")
          .text(null)
          .graphic(anchorPane)
          .position(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT)
          .hideAfter(Duration.minutes(1));

  notification.show();
```

I got the hint from here: [ControlsFX Issue Tracker](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/597/notifications-stacking-works-incorrectly)